# Vuejs - Cannot access array element using v-for in child component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm passing an array from a parent component to a child. The array is being passed and I can access the entire array, but for some reason when I try and access on array element I can't.

(This is shortened for brevity's sake)

When I do this:

```
<template v-for="creds in amazonCredsArray">
<v-container fluid grid-list-lg class="come_closer">
  <v-layout row wrap>
    <v-flex xs12>
      <v-card class="lightpurple">
        <v-card-title>
          <v-icon class="my_dark_purple_text">language</v-icon>
          <h1 class="title oswald my_dark_purple_text pl-2 pr-5">ENTER YOUR AMAZON CREDENTIALS BELOW</h1>
        </v-card-title>
     <v-form ref="form" v-model="valid">
      <h1>{{amazonCredsArray}}</h1>
```

I can see the `amazonCredsArray` displayed.. it looks like this:

```
[ { "auth_token": "amzn.mws.9cb254dXXXXX", "seller_id": "CXDFDFDF", "marketplace": "asdfasdfasdf", "zones": [ { "name": "United States", "id": 1 } ] }, { "auth_token": "asjdfljakldfjlsadf", "seller_id": "ddeeee", "marketplace": "12", "zones": [ { "name": "United States", "id": 1 } ] } ]
```

However when I try to use `creds` in that same place in the view, I don't get anything. I'm trying this:

```
<template v-for="creds in amazonCredsArray">
<v-container fluid grid-list-lg class="come_closer">
  <v-layout row wrap>
    <v-flex xs12>
      <v-card class="lightpurple">
        <v-card-title>
          <v-icon class="my_dark_purple_text">language</v-icon>
          <h1 class="title oswald my_dark_purple_text pl-2 pr-5">ENTER YOUR AMAZON CREDENTIALS BELOW</h1>
        </v-card-title>
     <v-form ref="form" v-model="valid">
      <h1>{{creds}}</h1>
```

Comment: maybe its because your using v-for directive on the root tag. (<template>). its forbidden in vuejs. try wrapping your content in one root element. it should help.

Comment: Great thanks.. heck I'll try anything

Comment: @Elfrat, root tag(template) can be used with v-for for iteration (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-on-a-lt-template-gt). Toddt, I created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OaRbJL?editors=1111) and it appears to work well. Something else may be blocking or causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
<template v-for="(creds, index) in amazonCredsArray" :key="creds.seller_id">
```